Can I take tea with me to Canada?

meine Frage war ob man Tee durchs Flugzeug von Deutschland nach Kanada mitnehmen darf.
Ich habe meinem Mann ein kleines Päckchen für seine Reise mitgegeben in dem es auch Teebeutel gibt.
Könnte das ihn in Schwierigkeiten bringen?

My question is whether you can take tea on a plane from Germany to Canada.
I gave my husband a small package for his trip that also contains tea bags.
Could he take it with him without trouble?

TLDR: Yes, you can.
Explanation: According to Canadian Food Inspection Agency (as per info given here) in the section Products allowed into Canada from countries, you are permitted to bring coffee and tea,as long as it does not exceed the allowed weight limit, which is 20 kg according to the regulations.

As it is food he should declare it at entry to the customs officer
